# Numbering equations differently before sections start within chapter

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I would like to number equations in the following way:

Chapter 1

x^2 + y^2 = z^2 (1.1)

x^3 + y^3 \neq z^3 (1.2)

Section 1.1

a^2 + b^2 = c^2 (1.1.1)

\sqrt{-1} = - \sqrt{-1} (1.1.2)

etc.

Currently the best I can achieve is to have (1.0.1), (1.0.2), etc., before the first section in the chapter. Aesthetically I find the unnecessary 0's quite ugly. Is there a way to tidy it up?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x^3 + y^3 \neq z^3
\end{equation}

\section{Next}
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{-1} = - \sqrt{-1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the section counter is zero ... -> The additional level of chapter can be suppressed. Similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245988/124842 for sections.

You nedd `\usepackage{amsmath}` package for MWE.

So you can add to your preamble:

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0 %
    \thechapter
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{equation}%
}
```

Solution:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0 %
    \thechapter
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{equation}%
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x^3 + y^3 \neq z^3
\end{equation}

\section{Next}
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{-1} = - \sqrt{-1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, How can you do the same, but in my case I want the numbering to be different in the appendix. for example I have in the chapter the equation (1.2.3), in the appendix I want (A.1), (A.2), etc independently on the section.

Comment: @Oscar .My first guess is something like : `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A.\arabic{chapter}}` after `\appendix`. Does it fit your problem? - General: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.