# numbering equations sectionwise

Tags: equations, numbering, labels

I have align environments in each section of my TeX file and I use \numberthis\label to label the last equation in the align environment. But this labels or numbers the equations in the order they are in the file. Can I have a sectionwise numbering of the equations in the align environments? For example, the last equations of the 1st and 2nd align environments(assuming I have only got 'align' environments) in section A to be labeled as A.1 and A.2?

MWE-

```
\documentclass[english,aps,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4-1} 
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\begin{document}


 \section{section1}

 \begin{align*}
  x&= 1\\
   &= 21313\numberthis\label{eqn}
 \end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 x&=    1\\
  &=    2324\numberthis\label{eqn}
 \end{align*}


 \section{section2}

 \begin{align*}
  x&=   1\\
   &=   34\numberthis\label{eqn}
 \end{align*}

 \begin{align*}
 x&=    2\\
  &=    345\numberthis\label{eqn}
 \end{align*}


 \end{document}
```

In this example, I have 4 equations and they get numbered from 1 to 4. I want to keep using the align environment and \numberthis command. And want to have numbering based on section like 1.1 and 1.2 (or A.1 and A.2) for the equations in the first section. How do I change the scope of numbering with \numberthis?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) with `\documentclass` and `\end{document}`. Related: [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/124842) or [Change the type of equation numbering in document class article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54242/124842)

Comment: With `\usepackage{nameref}` and an redefinition of `\renewcommand*{\theequation}`([Numbering equations differently before sections start within chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355145/124842))(with [\currentname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75183/124842) )you can get it. If you need further help please provide a MWE.

Comment: @user25957: It's a fragment still. There's no `\documentclass` and `amsmath` is missing as well

Comment: `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`? BTW, the `\addtocounter{equation}{1}` should really be `\refstepcounter{equation}`.

Comment: Thanks! I should have found this in the other answers. My bad. I was under the impression that I don't have an equation since I am working with the align environment. What is the difference b/w addtocounter and refstepcounter?

Comment: potential duplicate: [Change the type of equation numbering in document class article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54241/579).  to answer the question about what's the difference between `equation` and `align`, in this respect `equation` is used as a catch-all for all numbered display math, so it also covers `align`, `gather`, etc.

Comment: Your code is slightly weird: You ask about how to apply a certain numbering style for your equations, yet you use `align*` environments, which by design don't generate any equation numbers. How do you expect to generate equation numbers of any kind using `align*` environments? Also, using the same argument for `\label` four [4!] times is bound to create havoc. It certainly will generate lots of warning messages...

Comment: Mico, actually it works perfectly well. I don't know other ways to number only the last line in the align environment. Also, as barbara stated, "equation is used as a catch-all for all numbered display math, so it also covers align, gather, etc."

Comment: Is your question well answered? Or do you need the type "section name.number" like "Chapter One.1", "Chapter One.2" for  equation 1 and 2 in chapter one?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it will be better if it is answered in all details. I want to know for example if I can name a section S and subsections S1,S2 and so on. And equations inside the subsection to be S1.1, S1.2 and so on. It will be nice to know how to number the equations for any way of naming the section or subsection.